# Trying to insert Contact, getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm attempting to insert a Contact to the `Mirror API`, but I keep getting a `400 Bad Request` error.

My code to build the request is as follows:

```
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest firstPost = new HttpRequest();
    firstPost.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/contacts');
    firstPost.setMethod('POST');
    firstPost.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +access_token);
    System.debug('Bearer '+access_token);
    firstPost.setBody(postBody);
    firstPost.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

The postBody is hardcoded for now as:

```
{
 "kind":"mirror#contact",
 "id":"harold",
 "displayName":"Harold Penguin",
 "imageUrls": ["https://developers.google.com/glass/images/harold.jpg"]
}
```

I've confirmed the access_token is being sent.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you get no request body with that explaining what the error might have been …?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (and should not specify) the `kind` attribute when doing `contact.insert`. This is assumed (you better be inserting a contact), and I can see how it might be causing problems if you provide it. Notice that https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/insert does not list it as an attribute, and the Raw HTTP example does not show it.